# linq Take return null exception if the list is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I was facing one challenge is, I am using LINQ to get the first 5 records using  Take method, but if the list is empty then its throwing following exception:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

So please guide me how I can resolve it.

Below I am providing my sample code

```
openTickets_Result = (from tic in db.Tickets1
                      join com in db.Company on tic.company_id equals com.id
                      join bra in db.Branch on tic.branch_id equals bra.id
                      join use in db.Users on tic.assinged_to equals use.Id
                     where companyIds.Any(x => x.Equals((long)tic.company_id)) 
                     && branchIds.Any(x => x.Equals(tic.branch_id))
                     && tic.status == "Open"
                     && tic.priority == "High"
                      select new Details {
                           Assinged_To = use.FullName,
                           Company_Name = com.name,
                           Branch_Name = bra.branch_name,
                           ticketName=tic.Name
                      }).OrderBy(x => x.Create_Date).Take(5).ToList();
```

The Take method is giving an exception if the list sometime is `empty/null`.

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: `Take` operates on a collection level (not a single item level). If the list is empty, you won't get any results. You won't get `null`, however. It seems more likely that the list isn't empty and the item or `Create_Date` is null.

Comment: @TanvirArjel, **Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.**  this is the error message.

Comment: Problem have nothing to do with `Take`, check you `Where` statement does types are correct, are you executing this query against database?

Comment: Variables of what types are `companyIds` and `branchIds`?

Comment: @Fabio, its list of long type `List<long> companyIds = new List<long>();
                List<long> branchIds = new List<long>();`

Comment: @shibu Is company or branch id nullable? can you show?

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana, no all are not null

Comment: Replace `.Equals` method with equals sign and remove redundant casting `companyIds.Any(x => x == tic.company_id)` for `branchIds` list as well

Comment: @Shibu can you remove the cast for tic.company_id?

Comment: Starting to comment out where condition code might help you to identify problems quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as **branchIds** is long not null type ,**x => x.Equals(tic.branch_id)** and here tic.branch_id is long null type ,so need to typecast it

```
openTickets_Result = (from tic in db.Tickets1
                      join com in db.Company on tic.company_id equals com.id
                      join bra in db.Branch on tic.branch_id equals bra.id
                      join use in db.Users on tic.assinged_to equals use.Id
                      where companyIds.Any(x => x.Equals((long)tic.company_id)) && branchIds.Any(x => x.Equals((long)tic.branch_id)) && tic.status == "Open" && tic.priority == "High"
                      select new LiveTickets
                      {
                          Assinged_To = use.FullName,
                          Company_Name = com.name,
                          Branch_Name = bra.branch_name,
                          ticketName=tic.Name
                      }).OrderBy(x => x.Create_Date).Take(5).ToList();
```

> Anyway thanks to all for your support.